# Git commits associated with unknown user from foreign country

Tags: git

Apologies if a similar question has been asked before.

I have a professional (private) and a hobby (public) GitHub account. I work on robotics projects over the weekend and push to my hobby account from two different computers: a Linux and a MacOSX machine.

My user.name and user.email are my actual credentials for my Linux machine and pushing from my Linux machine yields no problems.

I was **young and dumb** and used some throwaway credentials on my MacOSX machine it seems (i.e. user.name = fakename, user.email = 123@fake.com). **GitHub reports that some account from Germany (not fakename) is pushing from my machine** every time I push from my MacOSX.

I'm assuming this fix is as easy as updating my user.name and user.email configs however I want to preserve this issue until I find out more. **Is it possible that my MacOSX machine is compromised?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GitHub commit *author* is associated to a GitHub account through its *email*, so it is possible that another (Germany) account actually has `123@fake.com` as an email.

But: this (user.name/user.email) has nothing to do with GitHub *authentication* (username/password). It is still *you* who are pushing to GitHub. Your commit though are not displayed as you because of the fake email.

See "[Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user)"

You can change that for new commit by setting the right email.
And you can change that for the past commits by following "[Changing author info](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info)".

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I had a feeling I was missing something going on under the GitHub hood (so to speak). I updated my credentials on the MacOSX end and this fixed the problem.